# Text font decreases on landscape view using android:freezesText="true"

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `android:freezesText="true"` to display the result in "**TextView**". I have set `android:textSize="12sp"` in this textView.

When I run the app, the result is displayed fine if the mobile is held in portrait view but when I rotate it to landscape view (for which I have separate layout file in layout-land), the font of the text is decreased and remain the same size even if I rotate the phone to portrait.

Please help to ensure that the text font size remains constant even when the phone is in portrait or landscape mode.

Thanks in advance. 
Following is xml code for textView:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2" />
```

Comment: is the textview same defined for both layouts?

Comment: Yes, it's same in both the layout.